# Telerik getting selected ID (Get data from Radgrid selected item)

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I can get the selected index of the gridview but i want to get the actual data that is inside the grid. I want to select a row in the grid and be able to access the "Client Id" column's actual data value. The grid is working fine and I am able to access the SelectedIndexChanged event. I have then been trying with no luck to find a way to get the information that is displayed in the grid. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Again, I need to get access to all data that is displayed in the grid form the codebehind.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822075/cannot-identify-selected-page-in-telerik-grid-i-need-selected-page-to-be-underl Help me in this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822075/cannot-identify-selected-page-in-telerik-grid-i-need-selected-page-to-be-underl

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is what data keys are for. Just designate the columns you want to access as data keys, like in the example shown below.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" ...>
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Column1, Column2, Column3" ...>
        ...
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik>
```

Once the data keys have been assigned in the markup, you can access them in code-behind by row, or using the `SelectedValues` property.

```
if (RadGrid1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    //access a string value
    string column1 = RadGrid1.SelectedValues["Column1"].ToString();

    //access an integer value
    int column2 = (int)RadGrid1.SelectedValues["Column2"];
}
```

Comment: @Jonathan O: To add to James' answer: If you need to `have access to all data that is displayed in the grid` for a particular row selected; you would need to have each column listed as a DataKey in the markup. Or... just list the ID and query your data store just for that particular item.

Comment: when you do this, what is in the variable column1? how does this get the data in that column? Thanks so much for helping.

Comment: So I have the DataKeyNames="ClientID, Gender, First Name" in my markup and in my codebehind... var column = rgSearchResults.SelectedValues["ClientID"].ToString;?? This is not working for me. The error says "object ref not set to an instance of obj"

Comment: Sorry, specify the `DatakeyNames` in the `MasterTableView`

Comment: @Jonathan O... Column1 was just an example James put in there for you. You should put whatever Properties you are binding to. For example, if you are binding your grid to a DataTable that has columns such as "Id","Name","Address", then your DataKeyNames should be "Id,Name,Address"... do you follow?

Comment: And, you will need to validate that an item is selected before getting the selected values.

Comment: THANKYOU!!!! THIS WORKED. Also, make sure that you have a datakey for each column.

Comment: @JamesJohnson I'm trying to create a foreach to read all SelectedItems, any tips on how to accomplish this?

Comment: @Michel: You should be able to iterate over the `SelectedItems` collection without an issue. Are you not able to??

Comment: get it =) [How to get all item values from RadGrid DataKeyName when implementing paging](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/how-to-get-all-item-values-from-radgrid-datakeyname-when-implementing-paging.aspx)

Comment: I spent hours researching this and then I came across your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```cs
foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items)
{
    if (item.selected == true)
        string mydata = item["ColumnName"].Text;
}
```

I recommend you read the documentation on this site http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/grdaccessingcellsandrows.html; it will sure help you a lot with Telerik components.

Comment: -1 This is not a good way to find the selected item or get the selected values. You should use data keys for getting the values, and you can use `RadGrid1.SelectedItems` to get the selected item(s). I suggest that you read some more documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use DataKeys as [James Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/879420/james-johnson) suggested. You cannot access `DataItem` property of the `GridDataItem` in `SelectedIndexChanged` event. It will be null. According to [Telerik documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/radgrid-telerik.webcontrols.griditem-dataitem.html) "DataItem object is available only when grid binds to data."

When `DateItem` is available, as in the `ItemCreated` event, you could do a cast to your original data type `MyType`:

```
private void RadGrid_ItemCreated(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Item is GridDataItem)) {
        GridDataItem gridDataItem = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
        MyType dataItem = (MyType)gridDataItem.DataItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this misses the boat. OP wants to know how to get the data from the `selected` item in the grid. Again, this is what data keys are for.